# Powershell - Get an excel file reviewed to check if users are available on AD or not with export

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm encountering an issue with my PSS:
ERROR = `Get-ADUser : Variable: 'userUPN' found in expression: $userUPN is not defined.
At C:\Users\toulayoh\OneDrive\Desktop\script\dataipadchecker.ps1:33 char:13

- ```
  $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $userUPN}-Prope ...
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`

So the explanation is I need to get users status from a xls file so I need compare AD with those users.

But the thing is this is the `DisplayName` that is located into the Excel file (for example: SMITH John)

Whenever my script is working, either cannot find users under AD or simply add the column with enabled for all user, but I've intentionally put a disabled one at the end of my file, but he appears Enabled...

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
# Import the required AD module
# Install the Import-Excel module if not already installed
# You can run this command once: Install-Module -Name ImportExcel

# Import the required module
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

# Specify the path to your input Excel file DevicesWithInventory_8962b92a-5661-4aa7-addd-40c3fb4a8a6e.csv
$excelFile = "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\testdoc.xlsx"

# Specify the path to the output CSV file
$excelFile2 = "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\outputdata.xlsx"
# Specify the name of the worksheet containing the user data
$worksheetName = "Sheet1"

$excelData = Import-Excel -Path $excelFile

$users = Import-Excel -Path $excelFile -WorksheetName $worksheetName


# Import the Excel data

# Create an array to store the results
$results = @()

# Iterate through each user and check their AD status
foreach ($users in $excelData) {
    $userUPN = $users.'Column 6'
    $outputcolumn = $users.'Column 10'

    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $userUPN}-Properties extensionAttribute15

$result = [PSCustomObject]@{
    UPN = $userUPN
    ExtensionAttribute15 = $user.extensionAttribute15
}
$results += $result
}

$results | Export-Excel -Path $excelFile2 -WorksheetName "Sheet1" -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow
```

If you guys had an idea i would gladly check it.

Comment: `DisplayName` is a calculated property member. It needs to be specified as a property to produce. `Get-AdUser -Properties DisplayName -Filter { DisplayName -eq $DisplayName }`

Comment: @lit Hello, thanks for your help and your informations, 
But unfortunately this don't seems to work out : 
Get-ADUser : Variable: 'displayName' found in expression: $displayName is not defined.
so i tried to replace displayname by user still KO
and eve tried to move the variable definition upper into the script ($displayName = $user.$displayNameColumn)

Comment: How does the value of `$displayName` get set? What is the value of `$displayName` before it is used as a parameter to `Get-AdUser`? This works. `$displayName = 'David Smith'; Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -eq $displayName } -Properties DisplayName` Note that there may be several AD users with the same `DisplayName`.

Comment: @lit, that's what I thought just after I had few times this error either of you guys reaction, I'll look forward and keep you updated

Comment: What debugger are you using? VS Code?

Comment: Hello @lit
Im using PS Script Analyzer and PS ISE.

Comment: @lit my variable `$displayName` is well definied line above : `foreach ($user in $users) {$displayName = $user.$displayNameColumn` [...] }` but actually might be an issue with the definied variable. have you an idea ?

Comment: I do not know debugging in ISE. But, I do know "The PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development." and "There is no support for the ISE in PowerShell v6 and beyond.". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: I encourage you to move to VS Code or another capable debugger. Step down to where the `$displayName` variable is set. Plug that value manually into a `Get-AdUser` command to see that it runs successfully. What version of PowerShell are you running? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`

Comment: Hello @lit i did finaly use VS code to edit my PSS, and actually looks better than what i did expected. So thanks. 
could you give a check to the second post i made ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76539952/powershell-import-excel-how-to-get-table-column-variable

i updated my code on this page to make things clearer, but still got issues on the current file tbh, i let it for later
 PS.Version = 5.1.19041.2673

Comment: `winget install --id Microsoft.Powershell --source winget` Now downloading current PS version

Answer (score 0):

In your first set of code you can use the filter like:

`$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -eq $displayName } -Properties enabled`

That should work.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your help, 
doesnt seems to work : 

    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { DisplayName -eq $displayName } -Properties enabled
   

ERROR : Variable: 'displayName' found in expression: $displayName is not defined.

Comment: I would recommend adding a breakpoint and debug the code at below line `$displayName = $user.$displayNameColumn` and see if the value is picked correctly for `$user.$displayNameColumn`

Answer (score 0):

When you just use single quote it wont execute the variable, and you'll generally have to use both double and single qoutes for the filter.
Try this:

```
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$displayName'" -Properties enabled
```

Single qoutes can exits within double qoutes and then they wont cause problems with execution.
[Image that shows the difference in an editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl3Ml.png)

Make sure that your input is a valid string, I have not worked with the Import-Excel module, I prefer using .csv but I get that is not always an option.
You could pass this into your loop or if ISE has loaded the variable to memory just pass into the terminal window of ISE:

```
$displayName | Get-Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty typename -Unique
```

Expected outcome:
[Type of the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSSQ6.png)

I'm pretty sure that your variable is not a string but it probably has a method for converting it to a string, try:

```
$displayName.ToString()
```

When you define your variable $displayName, you could also define it as a string and PowerShell should sort it out.

```
[string]$displayName = $user.$displayNameColumn
```

Comment: Hello Primycha, 
i tried your solution: 
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$displayName'" -Properties enabled -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

ERROR: 
Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At C:\Users\toulayoh\OneD\Desktop\script\testexcel.ps1:35 char:15
+ ...$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$displayName'" -Prop ...
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException   FullyQualifiedErrorId:ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetAD Us

Comment: Hmm weird, that exact code works for me, what have you put in your variable, is it a string? $displayname = "Takahashi Misaki" for example. Try $displayname | get-member and check the type info, should be system.string