# Powershell - Import-Excel - how to get table column variable

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

Here is my code,
But actually, got an issue to define a column in excel `$columnF = $excelFilePath.$WorkSheet.Columns.Item(6)` & `$userUPN = $row.$columnF`
did search online without finding it, thanks in advance for your help

So the Script seems to work as i got the error message `Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' not found."` that is prompt in console as you can see

```
# Install the ImportExcel module
# Install-Module -Name ImportExcel

# Import the module
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

# Specify the path of the source Excel file
$excelFilePath = "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\testdoc.xlsx"

# Specify the path of the destination Excel file
$exportFilePath = "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\outputdata2.xlsx"

$worksheet = "Sheet1"
#  Select data in columns.
$columnF = $excelFilePath.$WorkSheet.Columns.Item(6)
# Load the Excel data
$excelData = Import-Excel -Path $excelFilePath

# Initialize an empty array to store the results
$results = @()

# Process each row in the Excel data
foreach ($row in $excelData) {
    # Get the UPN from column 6 'Column 6'
    $userUPN = $row.$columnF

    # Retrieve the user object from Active Directory
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq "$userUPN"} -Properties extensionAttribute15

    if ($user) {
        # Create a custom object with the UPN and extensionAttribute15 value
        $result = [PSCustomObject] @{
            UPN = $userUPN
            ExtensionAttribute15 = $user.extensionAttribute15
        }

        # Add the result to the array
        $results += $result
    } else {
        Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' not found."
    }
}

# Export the results to a new Excel file
$results | Export-Excel -Path $exportFilePath -AutoSize -NoHeader

Write-Host "Export completed successfully."
```

try to get data from excel worksheet table but cannot define column variable

Example file:

[image: sample]

Comment: `$excelFilePath` is just a string, perhaps you meant to use `$xlsx = Open-ExcelPackage $excelFilePath` ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Hello, isnt `$excelData = Import-Excel -Path $excelFilePath` work the same way then `$xlsx = Open-ExcelPackage $excelFilePath` 
What are the differences and how should i add it into my PSS?

Comment: Not really, `Open-ExcelPackage` is for when you need to update or get the metadata of your file, usually when there is no cmdlet available for what you need to do. `Import-Excel` tries to create an array of objects with the data of your file, similar output to `Import-Csv`

Comment: Looking at what it seems you're trying to do, note that `Import-Excel` has 2 parameters: `-StartColumn` and `-StartRow` which should be self explanatory, you're telling the cmdlet from where to start looking to generate the objects

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for the details! Let me try your solution : 
# Load the Excel data
`$excelData = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $excelFilePath -WorksheetName $worksheet`
#  Select data in columns.
`$columnF = $excelData.Columns.Item(6)`
`foreach ($row in $excelData) {$userUPN = $row.$columnF`

Seems that it's not working: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.+ `$columnF = $excelData.Columns.Item(6)`
Looks like i still cannot define the column variable

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your excel file including the headers?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes ofc : https://imgur.com/a/ZQ55r73
i want this script to get me each location from UPNS

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look for the task you're trying to accomplish. As you may see, the output produced by `Import-Excel` is very similar to the one produced by `Import-Csv`, just an array of objects which you can enumerate and use dot notation to get the values from.

```bash
# Specify the path of the source Excel file
$excelFilePath = 'C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\testdoc.xlsx'

# Specify the path of the destination Excel file
$exportFilePath = 'C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\outputdata2.xlsx'

$worksheet = 'Sheet1'

# Load the Excel data
$excelData = Import-Excel -Path $excelFilePath -WorksheetName $worksheet

# Process each row in the Excel data
$results = foreach ($row in $excelData) {
    # Get the UPN from column 6 'Column 6', you can use dot notation here ;)
    $userUPN = $row.'Primary user UPN'

    # Retrieve the user object from Active Directory
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$userUPN'" -Properties extensionAttribute15

    if ($user) {
        # Create a custom object with the UPN and extensionAttribute15 value
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            UPN                  = $userUPN
            ExtensionAttribute15 = $user.extensionAttribute15
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' not found."
    }
}

# Export the results to a new Excel file
$results | Export-Excel -Path $exportFilePath -AutoSize -NoHeader

Write-Host 'Export completed successfully.'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
Suggested $xlxs variable fetch with my document wich is perfect but the 
`$user` Variable as you wrote returned me an error. 
we might insted use `{UserPrincipalName -eq "$userUPN"}` as i wrote it above

here is the console output : https://imgur.com/iK5R5yr

Comment: @MisakiTakahashi the filter I have here is fine, are you sure those users exist in your Domain?

Comment: Yes im sure, this list been exported from AAD Device Manager, so all users might be part of domain.
here is one of the user im trying to search on the excel file, as you can see from this AD console he does appears as enabled. 
https://imgur.com/wPQLsT2

but actually they can be on other OU.

Comment: They being in another OU doesn't matter at all, `Get-ADUser` will search all OUs in your Domain. Does the userPrincipalName of that user in AD matches exactly to what you have in your Excel file? I'm afraid I can't help you more than that here. @MisakiTakahashi

Comment: Yes if i search differents mails adress from my excel file in AD, i got a result of user account as lastest screenshot i sent you

Comment: @MisakiTakahashi `UserPrincipalName` and `mail` are 2 different things and may not always be the same, perhaps you're looking to filter for `-Filter "mail -eq '$upn'"`

Comment: Omg, i feel so dumb... i didn't knew that, thanks a lot! 
so i tried and i keep getting by else promt console error `User with UPN 'ramon@xoxoxo.com' not found.` 
i'm depressed now...

but actually in my company UPN = mail at least in PS `Get-ADUser nuttakat -Properties mail` same values are displayed in UPN and mail

Comment: @MisakiTakahashi and that UPN / mail from `nuttakat` matches exactly to one of the cells in the `'Primary user UPN'` column of your Excel file?

Comment: yes it does, i feel pretty stuck at that point,
i'll try to make it fetch with AD using DisplayName instead, maybe gonna be easier.